# React event.stopPropagation() doesn't work after element.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, stoppropagation

I have a div container with a button inside it. Both container and button have `onMouseDown` listeners. The button's listener, however, stops propagate the event. So:

- when I click on the container, "MouseDown" event is logged into the console,
- when I click on the button, nothing is logged, because button stops event bubbling.

So far so good. However, when I add `mousedown` listener with `addEventListener` to the container, it will be called even when I click on the button. So button's stopProgapagation() doesn't stops this listener from executing. Why? How can I fix that? [Here](https://playcode.io/1650291) is a full demo.

```
export const App = () => {
  const divRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    // Shouldn't be executed when I click on the button, but it is.
    divRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", () => console.log("NewMouseDown"))   
  }, [])

  return (
    <div onMouseDown={() => console.log("MouseDown")} ref={divRef}>
      <button onMouseDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}>Stop propagation</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: reacts events and the native ones are different mechanisms. What's the reason that you don't use reacts event listener? As you mention, there it works. Why do you need to work around react?

Comment: @Thomas I am using https://dragselect.com/ library for dragging and selecting items, this library uses addEventListener. I need to not select item when I click on a button inside it.

Comment: in that case I'd suggest something like `divRef.current.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { if (e.currentTarget !== e.target) console.log("NewMouseDown"); })` or maybe `if (!e.currentTarget.contains(e.target.closest("button"))) ...` and not intermingle react and native events.